# Twitter Typeahead.js in Node js NOT fetching suggestions

Tags: ajax, json, node.js, twitter-typeahead

**CODE USED FOR TYPEAHEAD :**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('input.typeahead').typeahead({
    name: 'Artist',
    prefetch:{url: '/queryjson, ttl: '1'},
    template: '<p><strong>{{firstname}}</strong>',
    limit : 10,
    engine: Hogan,
  });
</script>
```

**Code in App.js :**

```
app.get('/queryjson', function(req,res,next){
  var firstname = req.body.firstname;
  connection.query("select firstname from entries",
  function (err, rows, fields) {
    if (err)
    throw err;
    res.end(JSON.stringify({
      data : rows
    }));
  });
})
```

**AND FINALLY THE CODE FOR THE INPUT TEXT IN HTML :**

```
<input class="typeahead" type="text" placeholder="Artist" data-provide="typeahead">
```

*Note :* 
When i type /`queryjson` in the address bar, the rows generated by the database are available, and in a json format ( `{"data":[{"firstname":"sheila"},{"firstname":"Noreen"}...` )

But when i type something inside the input text, no suggestions are generated.

Do you have any idea on what might be possible the issues? I really, really need your help.

Or do you have any suggestions on the proper implementation of `typeahead` in node using `prefetch`?

Comment: You could format your code so it's better readable.

Answer (score 0):

you are missing a single quote! replace `'/queryjson,` with `'/queryjson',`

appart from that, it looks correct, http://jsfiddle.net/8GJh2/

Edit:  I also notice that your json format is different, [they do not include](http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/data/repos.json) the 'data' element

queryjson:

```
[
   { "firstname": "sheila"},
   { "firstname":"Noreen"}
]
```

App.js

```
res.end(rows);
```

Comment: Thanks! But i still can't generate suggestions. When i type something, nothing really happens. It's getting really frustrating.

Comment: edit my answer, you do not need `data:` in your json

Comment: Did your edits already. :) But i hope you would be really patient with me. Is it even possible to use the url '/queryjson' in the typeahead code? It seems like it does not really fetch the rows. Thus, no suggestions are generated.